# VMware and multiple network interfaces and ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vmware

I have a linux VM that Im assgining two network cards to.

```
eth0 (autodetect vmware settings)

eth1 (private to my mac vmware settings)
```

This is the content of my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
auto eth1
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet static 
    address 172.16.230.129
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.230.1
```

The reason for this setup is so that I can have a static IP on my vmware without limiting the connectivity.

ie: if I make eth0 static to a given IP and I move networks, I will not longer be able to connect. In the past, share with my mac has not worked in some network environments (my school)

With that said,

I want to be able to ssh into the my vm using the 172.16.230.129 connection.
However, its timing out right now.

any solutions?

Comment: People say it's a bad idea to post your actual IP address online.

Comment: the 172 subset of ip address are not public routes. Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

Comment: My bad. It may be a good idea to provide some details about the subnet from where you are trying to connect to the VM and whether you can reach that subnet from the VM. What do you mean by "limiting connectivity"? What exactly does "moving networks" involve? What is "share with my mac"? Is the VM at your school? --- I'm not trying to be annoying, but I find this question really difficult to understand.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo iptables -L -n -v --line` and `netstat -an | grep tcp` executed from within the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing, if you defined the gateway on eth1 and you set dhcp on eth0, dhcp normally releases a default gateway too, maybe for this reason you lose the connection

Comment: How do we fix it?